# ggplot2 : multiple factors boxplot with scale_x_date axis in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to create a multivariate boxplot time serie with ggplot2 and i need to have an x axis with boxplot position function of dates.

I created for that an interaction matrix with the combination of the factors `Treatment x Date` that is plotted against NDVI and with different trial groups:

here you can find some minimal data :

```
dat<-"Treatment  Trial.group    Date    NDVI
HighN   A   14/06/2013  0.27522123
HighN   A   14/06/2013  0.259781926
HighN   A   14/06/2013  0.175982276
LowN    A   14/06/2013  0.193604644
LowN    A   14/06/2013  0.261191793
LowN    A   14/06/2013  0.273672853
HighN   B   14/06/2013  0.192144884
HighN   B   14/06/2013  0.283013594
HighN   B   14/06/2013  0.230556973
LowN    B   14/06/2013  0.233952974
LowN    B   14/06/2013  0.261718465
LowN    B   14/06/2013  0.216450145
HighN   A   22/06/2013  0.37522123
HighN   A   22/06/2013  0.359781926
HighN   A   22/06/2013  0.275982276
LowN    A   22/06/2013  0.293604644
LowN    A   22/06/2013  0.361191793
LowN    A   22/06/2013  0.373672853
HighN   B   22/06/2013  0.292144884
HighN   B   22/06/2013  0.383013594
HighN   B   22/06/2013  0.330556973
LowN    B   22/06/2013  0.333952974
LowN    B   22/06/2013  0.361718465
LowN    B   22/06/2013  0.316450145
HighN   A   24/06/2013  0.47522123
HighN   A   24/06/2013  0.459781926
HighN   A   24/06/2013  0.375982276
LowN    A   24/06/2013  0.393604644
LowN    A   24/06/2013  0.461191793
LowN    A   24/06/2013  0.473672853
HighN   B   24/06/2013  0.392144884
HighN   B   24/06/2013  0.483013594
HighN   B   24/06/2013  0.430556973
LowN    B   24/06/2013  0.433952974
LowN    B   24/06/2013  0.461718465
LowN    B   24/06/2013  0.416450145"
```

Here is the code to import and create the plot :

```
NDVI_ts <- read.table(text=dat, header = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
interact<-interaction(NDVI_ts$Treatment, NDVI_ts$Date, sep=" : ")
ggplot(data=NDVI_ts, aes(x=interact, y=NDVI)) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Trial.group), width = 0.6) + 
theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

This code give me the following boxplot, which is fine, but the x-axis is not linked to dates : `(NDVI ~ Treatment + Date + Trial.group)`

[image]

I know that I can normally do that with something like this :

```
q + scale_x_date(breaks="1 week", labels=date_format("%d-%b"))
```

but the `interact` matrix is a factor and cannot be defined as a time object, so that doesn't work. I have the following error :

> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

How could I have multivariate boxplot positions defined by dates?

The NDVI_ts$Date is already defined as a date-object in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an x axis with the `interaction` between 'Treatment' and 'Date' may facilitate the arrangement of boxes of different value of the grouping variables. However, as you noticed, when the original `Date` axis is converted to a 'composite' factor, it is much harder to control appearance of the axis.

Here is an alternative which keeps the x axis in `Date` format. The two levels of 'Treatment' are distinguished by creating two different colours palettes. Groups within 'Treatment' are separated by different shades of the colour. Boxes are grouped by using the `group` argument.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)

# convert Date to class 'Date'
NDVI_ts$date <- as.Date(NDVI_ts$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

# A possible way to create suitable colours for the boxes
# create one palette of colours for each level of Treatment
# e.g. blue colour for 'HighN', red for 'LowN'
# one colour for each level of Trial.group

# number of levels of Trial.group
n_col <- length(unique(NDVI_ts$Trial.group))

# create blue colours
blues <- brewer.pal(n = n_col, "Blues")
# Warning message:
#   In brewer.pal(n = n_col, "Blues") :
#   minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels

# create red
reds <- brewer.pal(n = n_col, "Reds")

# Here I manually pick the first and the last 'blue' and 'red'
# From the plot in the question, it seems like you have more than two levels of Trial.group
# so you should be able to use the 'blues' and 'reds' vectors in scale_fill_manual.

# group boxes by date, Trial.group and Treatment
ggplot(data = NDVI_ts, aes(x = date, y = NDVI)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = interaction(Trial.group, Treatment),
                   group = interaction(factor(date), Trial.group, Treatment))) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 week", labels = date_format("%d-%b")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Treatment",
                    values = c("#FEE0D2", "#DE2D26", "#DEEBF7", "#3182BD"))
  #  scale_fill_manual(values = c(reds, blues))
```

[image]